# Image upload on cloudinary using meteor

Tags: meteor, cloudinary

iam using "lepozepo:cloudinary" meteor package to upload files to cloudinary from meteor app. the file is not uploaded and i am not getting any error. Appreciate if someone can point me what is going wrong. the following is the code.

```
Template.userprofile.events({
    "change input[type='file']": function(e) {
      console.log("iam in file upload")
     files = e.currentTarget.files[0];
       console.log("fiels value" + files)
    Cloudinary.upload(files,function(err,res){
    console.log("Upload Error:"  + err); //no output on console
    console.log ("Upload Result:" + res);        
    })    
    console.log("finsied" + files)
    }    
})
```

the following is the console output.

```
iam in file upload
fiels value[object File]
finsied[object File]
```

Comment: looks like package expects array file value, changed the files vaue to array, now getting the following error.
OPTIONS https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/dojoin/image/upload net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input(anonymous function) @ functions.coffee:110

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the problem is with the google chrome browser. But in firefox its working fine. Not sure how to handle this in chrome.